# Laravel session usage

Tags: php, session, laravel-4

I am using laravel apis for a web application.In my login route I am using Session::put('varaibleName','some string') I am using that login API in my web app.SO my question is how can I know whether the session is set or not.I have tried Session::get('variableName') in my webapp,but it is not working.Can I get the session variables in my webapp which is set in my laravel api??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session set or not you can check with method has

```
if (Session::has('data'))
{
    //
}
```

Comment: I am not using Views of laravel.I am just using the model and controller,My   html and php part of my web app is outside the laravel folder.